# Windows App certification Kit Fail Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm generating package for Windows Phone 8.1 app. Last week I was able to do it and to pass the certification test without problem.

Now I get the Error and I have no idea how to solve it

```
Parameter ppAsyncInfo of method RequestAsync of type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffOfflineDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd references the non-Windows Runtime type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.DownloaderResponse. Windows Runtime types can reference only Windows Runtime types.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.DownloaderRequest referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffOfflineDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.DownloaderRequest referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffOfflineDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.DownloaderResponse referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffOfflineDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
Parameter ppAsyncInfo of method RequestAsync of type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffProgressiveDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd references the non-Windows Runtime type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.DownloaderResponse. Windows Runtime types can reference only Windows Runtime types.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.DownloaderRequest referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffProgressiveDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.DownloaderRequest referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffProgressiveDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.DownloaderResponse referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffProgressiveDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
Parameter ppAsyncInfo of method RequestAsync of type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.DashDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd references the non-Windows Runtime type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.DownloaderResponse. Windows Runtime types can reference only Windows Runtime types.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.DownloaderRequest referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.DashDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.DownloaderRequest referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.DashDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.DownloaderResponse referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.DashDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Helper.ILifetimeAwareDownloaderPlugin referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffOfflineDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Helper.ILifetimeAwareDownloaderPlugin referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffOfflineDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.IDownloaderPlugin referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffOfflineDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.IDownloaderPlugin referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffOfflineDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Helper.ILifetimeAwareDownloaderPlugin referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffProgressiveDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Helper.ILifetimeAwareDownloaderPlugin referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffProgressiveDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.IDownloaderPlugin referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffProgressiveDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.IDownloaderPlugin referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.CffProgressiveDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.IDownloaderPlugin referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.DashDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.IDownloaderPlugin referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.DashDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Helper.ILifetimeAwareDownloaderPlugin referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.DashDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
The type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Helper.ILifetimeAwareDownloaderPlugin referenced by type Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.DashDownloaderPlugin in file Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.Dash.winmd was not found. All types referenced in metadata files must be discoverable.
```

They tell me to

```
Please ensure that the compiler you are using to generate your Windows Runtime types is up to date with with the Windows Runtime specifications.
```

I have no idea how to check that ...

Answer (score 1):

I updated Visual studio, the windows SDK, all nugets packages dependency.
I removed all references of the projects then I added references 1 by 1 (I guess I lost references I did not use).

I also updated the App certification kit. And the error miraculy disappeared.

Comment: I also had a similar problem. I also re-added my references, but that didn't work, so I then updated my Visual Studio 2015, after which it worked.